# I have a function that returns a list and I dont know how to reuse this list for compare it to another one

Tags: python, list

```
def show(x):
    ligne0 = "╔═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╦═══╤═══╤═══╗"
    ligne1 = "║ . │ . │ . ║ . │ . │ . ║ . │ . │ . ║"
    ligne2 = "╟───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╫───┼───┼───╢"
    ligne3 = "╠═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╬═══╪═══╪═══╣"
    ligne4 = "╚═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╩═══╧═══╧═══╝"

    valeurs = [[""]+[" 1234567890"[case] for case in ligne] for ligne in x]

    print(ligne0)
    for ligne in range(1,9+1):
        print("".join(n+s for (n, s) in zip(valeurs[ligne-1], ligne1.split("."))))
        print([ligne2, ligne3, ligne4][(ligne % 9 == 0) + (ligne % 3 == 0)])

def ligne(x, i):
    for ligne in x:
        return x[i-1]

grid_test = [
    [6, 2, 5, 8, 4, 3, 7, 9, 0],
    [0, 9, 1, 2, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3],
    [4, 0, 3, 9, 7, 1, 6, 2, 5],
    [8, 1, 0, 5, 9, 7, 2, 3, 6],
    [2, 3, 6, 0, 8, 4, 9, 5, 7],
    [9, 5, 7, 3, 0, 6, 8, 1, 4],
    [5, 6, 9, 4, 3, 2, 1, 7, 8],
    [3, 4, 2, 7, 1, 8, 5, 6, 9],
    [1, 7, 8, 6, 5, 9, 3, 4, 2],
]

valeur_p = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
show(grid_test)
print(ligne(grid_test, 1))
```

So I have the function ligne that return me a line i from a grid x and I dont know how to compare the elements in this list with another list

Comment: What's the point of a `for` loop that immediately returns?

Comment: You compare it the same as anything else, e.g. `if ligne(grid_test, 1) == some_other_list:`

Comment: Can you please write more and exact details? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to compare all the elements of a list with another similar list.

If yes, here's how you can do it,

```
list1 = ligne(grid_test, 1)

list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]  # replace it with whatever list you want to compare the list1

i = 0
while i<len(list1):
    if list1[i] == list2[i]:     # replace with the kind of comparison you want to do
       # do whatever you want to do after comparing
    i += 1
```

Note:
Since your question was not very clear, the above code is written with lot of assumptions in mind.

Comment: Hello, sry if my question was not very clear, so I just wanted to use the list which is returned by the function line and all i had to do is to put a variable on the funtion like: a = ligne(x, i) and a is the list I can work with. I just completely forgot I could do that